# c# string concat to get another variable

Tags: c#, string, variables

Good day. I would like to ask if it is possible to concatenate 2 strings to get another variable.

Lets say I have this code:

```
string num1 = "abcdefgh";
string num2 = "ijklmnop";
int numLength = 0;
```

And I want to get the value of both num1 and num2 using a forloop

```
for(int i =1; i<= 2; i++)
{
    numLength = ("num" + i).Length + numLength;
}
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0}", numLength);
```

I want it to output

> Length is 16

I did the above code but it actually gives me different value.

Edit1: (P.S. I will be using more than 10 variables, I just indicated 2 of it to make it simple)

Edit2: Yes, yes. I want ("num"+i).Length to give me num1.Legnth + num2.Length.

Comment: Why do you need a for loop? Shirely you need numLength = num1.Length + num2.Length;

Comment: ("num" + 1) is your problem, put the strings in an array of strings or as Aron says, but I suspect you're adding more than 2

Comment: You declared `num1` and `num2` but you never used them. What do you achieve exactly?

Comment: @Aron I will be using more than 10 variables so doing that style will take some time. I just posted 2 variables to make it simpler. I'll edit it anyway, to inform about this. Thanks!

Comment: @SonerGönül I need them for the length of that variable. (length of num1 and num2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First way**:

I suggest you to add all of your strings into the List and then get the total length with `Sum` method.

```
List<string> allStrings = new List<string>();
allStrings.Add(num1);
allStrings.Add(num2);
...
allStrings.Add(num10);

var totalLength = allStrings.Sum(x => x.Length);
```

---

**Second way**

Or if you want to calculate total length with `for` loop:

```
int totalLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < allStrings.Count; i++)
{
    totalLength = totalLength + allStrings[i].Length;
}
```

---

**Third way**

If you don't want to use `List`, then you can use `String.Concat` and then `Length` property.

```
var totalLength = String.Concat(num1, num2).Length;
```

The result is **16** in your case.

---

**Edit**:

In my opinion you think that, `("num" + i).Length` will give you `num1.Length` and `num2.Length`. This is wrong.

Comment: Yes, yes. I want ("num"+i).Length to give me num1.Legnth + num2.Length.

Comment: @PaZa: Use the `List<string>` instead. Then it's a case of `allStrings[i-1].Length` (or if you do your loop from `for (int i = 0; i < allStrings.Count; i++)` it'll be just `allStrings[i].Length` without the `-1`)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have some strings and we want the total length for all this strings.

In this case you need to store all strings in an array, so you can counter them and use indexes.

and after that a simple `for` (or `foreach`) loop can solve the problem:

```
            string[] texts = new string[20]; //You can use any number u need, but in my code I wrote 20.
            texts[0] = "sample text 1";
            texts[1] = "sample text 2";
            // add your strings ...

            int totalLenght = 0;
            foreach (string t in texts)
            {
                totalLenght += t.Length;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Length is {0}", totalLenght);
```

If you need a variable with unlimited size, use `List<T>`

here is example:

```
            List<string> texts = new List<string>();
            texts.Add("sample text 1");
            texts.Add("sample text 2");
            // add your strings ....

            int totalLenght = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++)
            {
                totalLenght += texts[i].Length;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Length is {0}", totalLenght);
```